# Reply management - New sub domain issue with Marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud

So we have many issues with the sub-domain that we are using with the marketing cloud. One of them is: If we want to reply to the emails from Outlook, we get an error message that says:

> Undelivarable and the content is: reply-fecc157376670c7c-2139_HTML-104564539-100025066-1 wasn't found at hello.ourSubdomain.com.

Also every time a client replies to one of our emails, `@hello.ourSubdomain.com` is getting appended at the end of their actual email address. 
We did whitelist our IP address and this was resolved for 2 days. But later, we started getting the same errors.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the MX entries for Marketing Cloud servers?

I think you need to use the localpart "reply" of your subdomain. So in your Reply Mail Management you need to set the domain like: reply.hello.ourSubdomain.com

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_dns_record_maintenance.htm&type=5

Comment: yes i have already did that

Comment: Can you post the settings of your sender profile and RMM?

Comment: Here is a note in the RMM: *Note: You must complete DNS Record redirect to the Marketing Cloud before Reply Mail Management can be activated.

Comment: Our email reply address is: reply@hello.oursubdomain.com

Comment: Ben, this is your reply subdomain? Do you have SAP or is this a private domain? This hello.oursubdomain.com is used only for RMM?

This note means you need to redirect your DNS to Marketing Cloud. After you contact you ISP and they make the changes you check this option as Yes

Comment: If this domain (hello.oursubdomain.com) is a private or a SAP, try using reply.hello.oursubdomain.com as you reply subdomain in RMM settings and anything@reply.hello.oursubdomain.com as your reply email in RMM settings

Comment: This domain is SAP. And is used also in the From address Management

Comment: That's what i was able to see in admin in email studio. I don't know much about DNS because this was set up by a third party. And if we want this to be fixed we will need to pay them more. If there is a quick solution for this that would be really helpful